# How to find number within a string in dataframe and re-format that number using thousands separator?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string-formatting

I have the below example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'City': ['Houston', 'Austin', 'Hoover','NY','LA'],
                   'Rules': ['ACH_CM > 28419581.51 and AMT_PM > 30572998.00 and AMT_PPM > 30572998.00 and AMT_CM > 30572998.00'
                             , 'MAA_PM and _AMT_PPM > 30572998.00 and _AMT_PM > 16484703.01 and AMT_CM > 28419581.51'
                             , 'MAA_PM and AMT_CM > 284 and AMT_PM > 30572998.00 and AMT_PPM > 30572998.00 and AMT_PPPM > 30572998.00 and ACH_AMT_PPM > 16484703.01'
                            ,'MAA_CM'
                            ,'_AMT_PPM > 30572.00']},columns=['City', 'Rules'])
```

Desired output:

```
City    Rules
Houston ACH_CM > 28,419,581.51 and AMT_PM > 30,572,998.00 and AMT_PPM > 30,572,998.00 and AMT_CM > 30,572,998.00
Austin  MAA_PM and _AMT_PPM > 30,572,998.00 and _AMT_PM > 16,484,703.01 and AMT_CM > 28,419,581.51
Hoover  MAA_PM and AMT_CM > 284 and AMT_PM > 30,572,998.00 and AMT_PPM > 30,572,998.00 and AMT_PPPM > 30,572,998.00 and ACH_AMT_PPM > 16,484,703.01
NY      MAA_CM
LA      AMT_PPM > 30,572.00
```

I believe I should be using `"{0:,.0f}".format` but not sure how to apply it.

Comment: I have edited the example to add row which do not contain any number

Answer (score 2):

This might be useful:

```
if len("%0.f" % floating.number) >= 5:
    print ('do something')
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
def _format(x):
    unformatted = re.findall("\d+\.\d+", df['Rules'].iloc[0])
    formatted = ['{:,}'.format(float(x)) for x in unformatted]
    for i in range(len(unformatted)):
        x = x.replace(unformatted[i], formatted[i])
    return x

df['Rules'] = df['Rules'].map(_format)
```

Comment: Thank you but this would not work if any given row has more than 1 float, for example in the the 2nd this is not picking up this _AMT_PM > 16484703.01 and converting it to thousand separated float.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
df['Rules'] = df.Rules.apply(lambda x: re.sub("\d+\.\d+", my_func, x))
```

where `my_func` is defined below:

```
def my_func(matchobj):
    f = float(matchobj.group(0))
    return "{0:,.2f}".format(f)
```

Comment: I guess your point is to put comma as thousand separator. So if in case you have number 2345, you will expect 2,345.

Comment: Thank you, that is almost what i need! The only modification i need to make in order to adapt and generalize for my current problem is modify the regex to:[ '\d{4,}.\d+']

Comment: Sorry, here is the comment properly formatted: Thank you, that is almost what i need! The only modification i need to make in order to adapt and generalize for my current problem is modify the regex to:  `\d{4,}.\d+` and in lambda to  `str(x)`

Comment: @MartinPetrov,  Why do you need to modify the regex and `str(x)`? I'm learning

Comment: because i want to capture only numbers which are 1000 and above, and as for the `str(x)` i am applying this to a dataframe with thousands rows and if i don't specify the `str(x)` it does read the x it as a pd.Series and throws me an error.

Comment: `{0:,.2f}` will automatically put comma only for thousand. So `\d+\.\d+` won't make any side effect to numbers < 1000 captured.

Comment: Thanks bakka, that makes sense.